Can Bazel be used for caching mechanisms?
I am building Android images (OS) not APKs. Likewise whenever changes is made in code, I'll be building new image each time to test the changes. Now as a mechanism to speedup the android build, can i use Bazel tool? If so, how can I implement it?
